# How do I setup up the backup configurations on godaddy to a Ubuntu Linux server?

Tags: server, ftp

I need to fill out out my remote host, the backup directory, the remote account username and password and if it is a passive FTP. Help with understanding this hopefully from someone who has done this before thanks.